# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, foreach, this, bind

I have a question,

```js
// case 1
const stack = [];
[1,2,3].forEach(stack.push);
```

This will throw Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at push (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
```

But this will be fine,

```js
// case 2
const stack = [];
[1,2,3].forEach(element => stack.push(element));
console.log(stack); // [1,2,3]
```

And if you bind stack with `this` referring to itself,

```js
// case 3
const stack = [];
[1,2,3].forEach(stack.push.bind(stack));
console.log(stack); // (9) [1, 0, Array(3), 2, 1, Array(3), 3, 2, Array(3)]
```

It also works in another way.

How can these happen? What is the difference between a method(case 1) and an arrow function(case 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack.push` references `Array.prototype.push`. This:

```
const stack = [];
[1,2,3].forEach(stack.push);
```

doesn't work because it's equivalent to:

```
const stack = [];
[1,2,3].forEach(Array.prototype.push);
```

or

```
const callback = Array.prototype.push;
callback(1, 0, [1, 2, 3]);
callback(2, 1, [1, 2, 3]);
callback(3, 2, [1, 2, 3]);
```

which doesn't work because there is no `this` context of the array to push to.

Method 2 works because you're doing `=> stack.push(element)` - `.push` is being called with a calling context of `stack`, rather than `stack.push` being passed as a callback. (When passed as a callback, the calling context gets lost unless you bind the function, which you do in the 3rd method).

For another example:

```js
const obj = {
  fn() {
    console.log('fn. this is:', this);
  }
};

const callback = obj.fn;
// this does not refer to the object now:
callback();

// but this will:
obj.fn();
```